# TeamCity, passing an id generated in one build step to a later build step

Tags: teamcity

New to TeamCity.  I have multiple build steps.  Step 3 generates an id that is needed in step 4.  What is the best way to pass the id (a string) between step 3 and step 4?  The build steps are written in Ruby.  Can I set an environment variable?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Yes, you can set an environment variable in one build step and use it in the following step. You will need to use a service message in your build script as described here http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-AddingorChangingaBuildParameterfromaBuildStep to dynamically update a build parameter, which you can use in the next step. Note, that it won't be available in the step that generates it, only in the next one.

Note that to set the variable, it must be written out somehow (`echo` for bash command-line, `write-host` for Powershell), in quotes. Example:

```
echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.ENV_AAA' value='aaaaaaaaaa']"
```

and to use this variable write `%env.ENV_AAA%` in the box in the next build step (Atleast in TeamCity 9.1.7))

Comment: Maria, thank you for the pointer.

I set the following in the ruby program executed by my TeamCity build step 3
puts "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.USER_DATETIME' value='#{DateTime.now}']"

and I set the following in the ruby program executed by my TeamCity build step 4
puts "... USER_DATETIME = '#{ENV['USER_DATETIME']}'"

And it worked!

Comment: I am not able to retrieve parameter value in next step without pre-defining it in `Build Configuration Settings->Parameters` section. 
According to documentation:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity  (see "Adding or Changing a Build Parameter")

@MikeJr: This did not work for me: `USER_DATETIME = '#{ENV['USER_DATETIME']}'"`
This worked: `echo %env.USER_DATETIME%`
Teamcity version is 9.1.6 (build 37459)

Comment: Updated documentation for anyone looking at this now: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-changingBuildParameterAddingorChangingaBuildParameterfromaBuildStepAddingorChangingaBuildParameter

Comment: You should not use "env." or any other prefix, otherwise TC will require the agent having this environment variable configured. For me just: `echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='MY_UNIQUE_VARIABLE' value='aaaaaaaaaa']"` worked