# Is it possible to set a variable in one build configuration and refer to it in subsequent, dependent configurations?

Tags: build, continuous-integration, teamcity

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

I have multiple dependent configurations for a single, logical build. The very first configuration runs a script that does a bit of work and returns a value. You can think of this configuration as the setup step. I need to be able store this value and use it in subsequent steps. All dependent configurations for a single build should receive the same value.

**Setup()** computes a value **x**. I then have configurations **B(x)** and **A(x)** that run after **Setup()** and need to be fed the calculated value **x**.

Previously, I've managed to do something similar for things that are calculated as part of the TeamCity configuration. E.g. I generated a unique build id for the entire build chain and was able to access it via %dep.{team_city_configuration_id}.system.build.number%.

This time, the value I need to propagate is calculated in the guts of a build script and not as part of the TeamCity plumbing. I've managed to wrap the setup script in question and grep out the value I need, but I don't know how to propagate it between configurations.

Is this even possible, or am I barking up the wrong tree? If I cannot do this in a non-insane way, is there a better alternative I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [TeamCity, passing an id generated in one build step to a later build step](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219493/teamcity-passing-an-id-generated-in-one-build-step-to-a-later-build-step)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can a mod close this, please? It's a dupe. My colleague [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219493/teamcity-passing-an-id-generated-in-one-build-step-to-a-later-build-step), which does exactly what we wanted.