# TeamCity - using setParameter to pass information between build steps

Tags: teamcity

I must be doing something differently than what was asked and answered here because the solution does not appear to be working for me: [TeamCity, passing an id generated in one build step to a later build step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219493/teamcity-passing-an-id-generated-in-one-build-step-to-a-later-build-step)

I want use a string generated by one build step in a final build step. So far I have set up an environmental variable called "TEST" that is empty. Both build steps use the Command Line Runner.

Build Step #1:

```
\##teamcity[setParameter name='env.TEST' value='test']
```

Build Step #2:

```
echo $TEST

echo %env.TEST%;
```

Placeholder for now, but if I could access the test string ('test') set in Build Step 1 I would be so happy.

Answer (score 50):

you need to echo that string, e.g.

```
echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.TEST' value='test']"
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for - the docs don't indicate that it needs to be echoed out, much less in quotes. After that, my next step had `$TEST` available.

Comment: just to re-iterate, the variable is only updated from the next TeamCity step onwards, the changes are not reflected in the current step

Answer (score 11):

What I found is that with long values, as soon as TeamCity is breaking down the log output into two separate lines **echo will not work anymore** - you have to use `Write-Host` instead.

```
Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.TEST' value='test']"
```

This should always work, just a side note - this value will be available only on *subsequent* build steps.

Comment: This does not address if you are not using windows. PS commands do not work on Unix agents

Answer (score 7):

To expand on the above answers, with powershell it would look like so in build step 1:

```
Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.TEST' value='$test']"
```

...and you can use the value like this in step 2:

```
echo %env.Test%
```

Also as a note, you'll have to set env.Test in the TC build parameters to be equal to something.  I just used a space since I know the value will be set via ps script.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

I think you have an extra "\" in there. Try removing that and add double quotes around it and it should work.

```
 "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.TEST' value='test']"
```

If it doesn't work try using Powershell runner type as I'm using that for setting it and it works.

Answer (score 6):

It has to be printed to STDOUT, I use `cat` with `heredoc` to avoid having to escape single quotes in the event of using variables to dynamically set config parameters. [What is heredoc?](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)

```
MYVARNAME=MYVALUE
cat <<EOF
##teamcity[setParameter name='myConfParameter' value='$MYVARNAME']
EOF
```

Result:

```
##teamcity[setParameter name='myConfParameter' value='MYVALUE']
```

[Documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity)

Comment: so you just downvoted without exchanging any more information about the matter? @PhateeP

Comment: sorry for downvote, but it simply does not work. It prints > and then > EOF in another line in console. It does not echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='myConfParameter' value='$MYVARNAME']" in to the console. Can you bring more info? I ll be happy to upvote if it realy works

Comment: `>` is printed by shell when you do multiline stuff like quotes, heredoc etc. you shouldn't use `>`

Comment: @PhateeP try again,I edited my answer to make it easier to understand

Comment: I've just checked it and now it prints nothing at all.

Comment: can you share your code in a github gist or pastebin maybe? @PhateeP . I tried again it works https://imgur.com/a/SwfNZ6t

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xPmfaDwz
I execute it in Build Steps, Runner type: Command Line. I also have defined that param in Parameters so it could be modified. Trying that code without defining param behaves exacly the same - prints nothing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171715/discussion-between-sdkks-and-phatee-p).

Comment: Options with "cat" was the only one working for me... echo did not catch it up !

Answer (score 0):

[Here is official ticket](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/1031952) about addition double quotes and echo (Write-Host - OS dependency).